# Sorting Array by ID Number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, controllers

My database has "spine numbers" and I want to sort by them.

```
@films = Film.all.sort{|a,b| a.id <=> b.id }
```

That is my one controller, but the spines go 1, 2, 3 ... 100, 101 etc. instead of 001,002,003... so the sorting is out of whack. There's probably an easy class for this something like:

```
@films = Film.all.sort{|a,b| a.id.abs <=> b.id.abs }
```

But I don't know it. Thanks for the help.

PS also, why has the rails wiki been down so often recently?

Comment: Can you post the result of the sort as well as the 'films' table definition from schema.rb?

Comment: Is there a reason you're sorting in this way? If not, go with @bassneck's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **Film.order("id DESC")** (or "ASC") method which aplies SQL *ORDER BY* clause to the query.
By default, records are sorted by the primary key column, at least in MySQL.

If this hasn't answered your question, please provide some more information on your database.

**Edited**
Yes, I do see. The only thing that comes to mind is that you're using some kind of string datatype for the spine numbers column. In this case, this kind of sorting makes sense, because values are compared alpabetically char to char like this

```
1| |
0|5|4
2|5|
1|4|3
```

which'll return

- 054
- 1
- 143
- 25

while numeric values such as integer, or float, are compared by their actual value, and not by separate bytes.

So you should create a migration to change the datatype of your spine number to integer.

Comment: I'm using the default sqlite3 database. Here is the link. http://criterion.heroku.com/films . As you can see it sorted the latest updated films to the bottom of the list. I wanted to know if I could sort by the spine number instead of the primary key, even though the spine numbers don't have zeros in front of them.

Comment: Uhm... as I can see, your primary key is spine number. Anyway, the order method allows you to sort data based on any column. Film.order("spine ASC") will return rows with the lowest spine number at the top and the highest at the bottom

Comment: http://criterion.heroku.com/films , there do you see now what I mean about the sorting and how its not reading it in the order I want because the spine numbers don't have preceding zeros, ie 001, 002